# Add Commas Between Permalinks

Tags: arrays, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, permalinks, acfpro

I have two CPTS created: People and Locations. On a single location page, you can see all people that work there. Once you click on a single person, you can see their bio as well as all location(s) he or she works at. I have created this set-up using the ACF relationship field.

Right now I have the following to show the locations within my **single-people.php**:

```
<?php if( $locations ): ?>
  <?php foreach( $locations as $location ): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $location->ID ); ?>">
      <?php echo get_the_title( $location->ID ); ?>
    </a>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

How can I modify this to insert a comma or a semicolon between the locations and still keep the permalinks?

A page with this issue is: https://aptw.nk-creative.com/people/james-gualtieri/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, this is all you need to do:

```
<?php if( $locations ): ?>
  <?php foreach( $locations as $location ): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $location->ID ); ?>">
      <?php echo get_the_title( $location->ID ); ?>
    </a>;
  <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

That is, after the `</a>` (which is HTML, not PHP) you can insert your separator. In this case, a semicolon.

Then, if you didn't want the semicolon after the last item, you could do this:

```
<?php
    if ( $locations ) {
        $i=1;
        $sizeof = count($locations);
        foreach( $locations as $location ) {
            echo '<a href="' . get_permalink( $location->ID ) . '">';
            echo get_the_title( $location->ID );
            if ( $i == $sizeof ) {
                // the final element, end with period / fullstop
                echo "</a>.";
            } else {
                echo "</a>; ";
            }
            $i++;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: I tried the second code snippet, but I am still having the last semi-colon print at the end of the list. Also to clarify, I don't need to use both, right? Originally, I read your post has having to use both code snippets and that duplicated the items in my list haha.

Comment: Sorry - I forgot to increment the $i variable... Note the new line $i++. This should now do the job. Also, correct, you don't need both - just use the 2nd block of code, replacing your original block of code. If this fixes your issue, please select my response as answering your query.